# "Verb+Ved" vs "Verb+Ving"

Tags: gerunds, participles

I ran a cross this sentence:

> Some experts believe that when we sleep **curled** up in a fetal position, we're exhibiting an unconscious longing for the sanctuary of the womb.

1. If *curled* is replaced by *curling*, would it be exactly the same in meaning?
2. Is "Verb + Ved" common in English? I somehow can't think of other examples, can I use Ved to describe verb freely as in the above sentence? For example: When he hit pierced the wood, he doesn't feel pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of understanding the participle phrase *Curled up in a fetal position*:

- Traditional grammar would understand it as an adverbial describing ***how*** we sleep.
- Many contemporary grammarians would understand it as a "secondary predicate"—that is, this construction is a way of incorporating a second description of the subject *we*, equivalent to "We are curled up in a fetal position* into the primary predication *We sleep*.

I incline toward the second interpretation because this aligns the construction with others which employ a frank adjective, making an adverbial interpretation very awkward:

> Her teeth gleamed **white** in the moonlight.
>   We allow our children to run **free** in the yard.
>   Some of us sleep **naked**, while others wear pyjamas.

*Curled* should be preferred over *curling* in this case:

- the *-ing* form (present participle) implies an action carried out or repeated throughout the action of the main clause:

  > He slept breathing heavily.
  >   He slept curling and uncurling restlessly.
- the *-en* form (past participle) implies an action carried out once and effecting a state which persists throughout the action of the main clause:

  > He slept curled up in a ball.
  >   He slept stunned by exhaustion.

Note that while with an intransitive verb the secondary predicate modifies the subject, with a transitive verb the secondary predicate may modify either the subject or the object:

> The waiters served our coffee {naked / dressed as 18th-century footmen}.
>   The waiters served our coffee {black / with whipped cream}.

You may examine other instances of this construction under the [secondary-predicate](/questions/tagged/secondary-predicate) tag.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slightly different meaning between using **curled** and **curling**. Both refer to a balled up position, the **fetal position** is a **curled up** position usually associated with babies having legs drawn in.

**Curled up** is the **name** of the position, similar to **upright**, **spread eagle**, or **flat**.
It refers to how one sleeps:

> When we sleep **curled up**, we take up less room on the bed.
>   When we sleep **stretched out**, we take up more room on the bed

**Curling up** would refer to the act of getting into a **curled up** position.

> When we sleep **curling up** into a ball...
>   When we sleep **stretching out** across the bed...